# Wrapping each type in a variadic template in a templated class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, tuples, variadic-templates

Given a variadic template `Types...`, I would like to store `A<>` for each of the types in the pack. This could be done in a tuple of `A<>`'s, but I'd need to programmatically derive the type of said tuple.

Is such a thing even possible in c++11/14/17?

```
template <class T> class A { };

template <class... Types>
class B
{
   // A tuple of A<>'s for each type in Types...
   std::tuple<A<Type1>, A<Type2>, ...> data;
};
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Simply with:

```
template <class... Types>
class B
{
   std::tuple<A<Types>...> data;
};
```