# Extract list of types from std::tuple for template class

Tags: c++, templates, stdtuple

Suppose I have the following class

```
class Example {
public:
    using value_type = std::tuple<
        uint8_t,
        uint8_t,
        uint16_t
    >;

private:
    value_type _value;
};
```

Now, I want to be able to create another class based upon this type that wraps each of the classes types in another type.  Based upon [Wrapping each type in a variadic template in a templated class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32336822/wrapping-each-type-in-a-variadic-template-in-a-templated-class), I know I can accomplish half my goal via:

```
template <typename T>
class Wrapper;

template <typename ... ARGS>
class ExampleWrapper {
private:
    std::tuple<Wrapper<ARGS>...> _args;
};
```

However, what I can't figure out is how to get `ARGS` if all I know is `T`, where `T` is Example.  I would like to be able to use `ExampleWrapper` as follows:

```
ExampleWrapper<Example> myWrapper;
```

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/6vGK9PEhY

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use template partial specialization to get `ARGS`:

```
template <typename T>
class Wrapper;

template <typename Tuple>
class ExampleWrapper;

template <typename ... ARGS>
class ExampleWrapper<std::tuple<ARGS...>> {
private:
    std::tuple<Wrapper<ARGS>...> _args;
};
```

Then:

```
ExampleWrapper<Example::value_type> myWrapper;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a static function to return the desired type and use [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) on it.

```
template <typename T>
class Wrapper{};

template<class T>
class ExampleWrapper {
    public:
    template<typename ...Args>
    static std::tuple<Wrapper<Args>...> fnc(std::tuple<Args...>);  
    using value_type = decltype( fnc( std::declval<typename T::value_type>() ) );

    private:
    value_type _args;  
};
// The type of `ExampleWrapper<Example>::_args` would be
// std::tuple<Wrapper<unsigned char>, Wrapper<unsigned char>, Wrapper<short unsigned int> >
}
```

There's no need to make the static function declaration and `value_type` alias public. I made them `public` just for the sake of demonstration.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/v8Y7zqxcW)